# Dell Streak for Android Development?

Tags: android

I am an iPhone developer that is about to dive into the Android market. The price of the development phone (Nexus 1 - $530) is quite high, so I thought to myself, "Why not spend $10 more and get something like the Dell Streak?". I haven't read any particular reviews on that device, but for an iPhone user that just wants a dependable device to develop on - what is the best fit? Ideally I am looking for a device that matches the experience that most Android users have - is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can hold off just a little longer you could get a **Samsung Nexus S** which is the latest Android phone and will be shipping with Gingerbread (2.3).

Comment: I can hold off until Dec. 16th - is that release date firm? What are the benefits of this device (aside from the updated OS)?

Comment: AS @Chris points out its marketed as a true "Google experience" so no modifications to the UI and also updates direct from Google.  Another point is its the first Android phone to come with near field communication (NFC).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look into statistics of device frequencies.

Android website provides http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html and OS versions.

But there are lot of other stats on the web, e.g.:

- http://www.enterra-inc.com/techzone/android_statistics/
- http://blog.tweetdeck.com/android-ecosystem
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any normal consumer-marketed android device can be used for application development - a developer phone is only needed if you want to modify the android platform and underlying linux itself (something that may also be possible by finding a way to root a consumer device)

To match the experience of most users, you probably want a recent device co-branded as a "google experience" device, ie one that comes with Android Market and the other google apps, which are not at present available for devices without that "blessing".

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at getting a motorola droid or droid 2 since they hold most of the android market share.  I think this would provide the ideal user experience.  I think the Samsung Nexus S will probably be THE android phone to have, but I dont think most people will have it for sometime.